# Segmentation Fault while creating thread using #include<thread>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am new to C++ multithreading.
I wrote a simple program to print hello world using threads.

```
<<mythread.cpp>>

#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
void hello()
{
std::cout<<"Hi this is a thread";
}


int main()
{

std::thread mythread(hello);
cout<<'1';
if (mythread.joinable())
        {
        cout<<'2';
         mythread.join();
        cout<<'3';
        }

return 0;
}
```

Copilation command : g++ -std=c++0x mythread.cpp

It compiled successfully but gave Segmentaion fault at run time.

I check the core file :

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003ac340df7c in _dl_fixup () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#1  0x0000003ac3414625 in _dl_runtime_resolve () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#2  0x0000003ac84b65c7 in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00000000004010d0 in std::thread::thread<void (*)()>(void (*)()) ()
#4  0x0000000000400e15 in main ()
```

Kindly help me to resolve this error it seems to be some library is not supportive.

Comment: I believe GCC requires use of `-pthread` command-line option when working with `<thread>`.

Comment: exactly, `g++` should give you linker errors when you run `g++ -std=c++0x -o mythread mythread.cpp` without `-pthread`. Your problem is not reproducible, because your command line doesn't produce an executable (but fails at generating one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program looks correct. Compile it with `-pthread` flag:

```
g++ -pthread -std=c++11 mythread.cpp
```

Comment: You have to also link with the same flag, in case you use separate compile and link steps.

Comment: @Sambhavjain In such case, consider [accepting the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (using the green check-mark next to it, max. one accepted answer per question). This marks the question as resolved, and gives both you and the answerer some reputation.